# how to use multer in update file and check the conduction for when file is not change?

Tags: node.js, multer

```
app.post('/manage/edit/:id', uploads, function (req, res) {

    if (req.file === undefined) {
        req.body.image = '/uploads/' + req.file.no - image.png;
    } else {
        req.body.image = '/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    }

    var id = req.params.id;
    Addbook.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: id
    }, req.body, function (err) {

        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        res.redirect('/manage/book-details')

    });
});
```